# 仕掛けてきてた in this context

Tags: meaning, words

In this context, would 仕掛けてきてた in 顔がもう仕掛けてきてたわ be:

1. to start; to begin; to commence​

or

2. to challenge; to pick (a fight); to make (war)

[image: Scene from the manga]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's closer to 2, except that what the guy tried to start with her was not a fight or a war. 仕掛ける can be used with anything that makes the other person upset or excited. "Your face was tempting me already!"

> #### [仕掛ける](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%95%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-517246)
>
> １ 相手に対して、こちらから働きかける。相手が乗ってくるように扱う。仕向ける。「技を―・ける」「けんかを―・けられる」